# Как правильно построить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

*И еще о подъемах и спусках.*

Никак не могу грамотно сформулировать фразу. 
Смысл такой:

> Лифт для спуска в шахту рабочих и грузов и подъема их на поверхность.

То есть, обобщающее слово "шахта", но как лучше будет выразить, что люди и грузы опускаются и поднимаются на этом лифте?

*Заранее спасибо.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Само понятие "лифт" уже предусматривает, что он работает в двух направлениях. Достаточно просто сказать "лифт для рабочих и грузов".

Answer (score 1):

А можно и так: Пасажирский и грузовой лифт.

Answer (score 0):

Правильный совет Сержа.
Можно, как в США. Пассажирско-грузовой лифт № 3 шахты Урочная, ствол (такой-то), спуск до 3-го горизонта. Грузоподъёмность: 16 чел. или (столько-то) килограммов. Рядом сертификат-оригинал: когда и кем проверен, до какого срока разрешение. Всё это на металлич. табличке и под внутр. замком для смены. Ключ у инспектора.
Примечание. Спуск на 5-й горизонт - лифт №4, ствол """

Answer (score 0):

1)Лифт для персонала и грузов.

2)Лифт грузоподъёмностью от ×× до ××тон.

3)с грузом или без , вверх или вниз :-)

4. легко и грузоподьёмный лифт

5)лифт максимально 5т

6)лифт здесь.